# Running FFmpeg in Azure Function app not working when deployed with Azure Pipelines

Tags: c#, azure, ffmpeg, azure-functions, .net-7.0

I'm unable to run ffmpeg in a .Net 7 isolated process Azure Function app in Azure after deploying it through Azure Pipelines. I can run it locally, and I've been able to run ffmpeg after deploying the app manually.

Here's an example of how I run the ffmpeg process. The `process.ExitCode` on exit is always '-1073741515' when it's been deployed through Azure Pipelines.

```cs
internal bool IsFfmpegExecutable(string ffmpegPath)
{
    try
    {
        using var process = new Process();
        var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = ffmpegPath,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            RedirectStandardError = true,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            CreateNoWindow = true,
            Arguments = "-version"
        };

        process.StartInfo = startInfo;

        process.OutputDataReceived += (_, _) => { };
        process.ErrorDataReceived += (_, _) => { };

        process.Start();
        process.WaitForExit();

        return process.ExitCode == 0;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The path to the ffmpeg.exe (along with the other ffmpeg dll and exe files) are correct, as I've checked it with `File.Exists()`. All those files are located in the C:\home\site\wwwroot\ffmpeg\ folder in Azure, as can be seen in Kudu: [image]

Any idea of how I can get it working?

Comment: I may have the impression there's some lock on the file which is raising the exception. I would recommend you switch to Azure Container Apps.

Comment: @tiago-castodio, thanks for your comment, it helped us realize that there was potential issues with permission access to the executables. See my answer for what fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the issue was caused by the .dll and .exe files not being accessible after we deployed the app through Azure Pipelines. This might be due to permission problems.

We had to have the .dll and .exe files zipped, followed by extracting them onto the local disk of the app (`C:/local/Temp` folder). Once the files were extracted, we were able to execute them.